# Why sine and cosine are orthogonal over continuum and over discrete set?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, orthogonality

Consider functions of $x$:

$$
1,\quad \sin \frac{\pi n}{N} x, \quad \cos \frac{\pi n}{N} x, \quad \cos \pi x
$$

where $n$ runs $1,\,2,\, \ldots,\,N - 1$

Those functions are orthogonal if the inner product is defined as
$$
\int_0^{2 N} f(x) g(x) \, dx
$$

but also if it is
$$
\sum_{x = 0}^{2 N - 1} f(x)g(x)
$$
What is special about the sine and the cosine? Do other sets of functions have a similar property.

As @badjohn suggested I experimented with four triangular functions:

[image]

The integrals and the sums are zero. The sums are zero also with a shift ($0 \le \delta < 1$, $N = 2$):

$$
\sum_{x = 0}^{2 N - 1} f(x + \delta)g(x + \delta)
$$

Comment: There is nothing special about it, the sine and cosine functions form a basis of the vector space of functions. You could do the same with negative exponentials as well

Comment: Take any infinite basis of functions, say $x^n$ (famous Taylor series) and a dot product (say, weighted with $w(x)$ integral of product over an interval), apply [Gram-Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) and you'll have such functions for the first property of OP, e.g. $[-1,1]$ with $w(x)=(1-x^2)^{\pm 1/2}$ gives [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials). @slitvinov

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Those sets of functions are not orthogonal over equally spaced points. Maybe one should takes some other set of points but I do not know which one.

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan Can you give an example?

Comment: You could probably do it with triangular waves.  A non-periodic example would be interesting.